# Questions on formation of cyclic ethers using Williamson Ether synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry

**question 1:**
[image]

In the synthesis, both intra- and intermolecular SN2 can undergo, in which only intramolecular reaction gives the cyclic ethers. However, both reactions happen in the reaction mixture. How can I alter the reaction conditions / add other reagents such that the intramolecular reaction becomes more favorable?

One [solution](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/williamson-ether-synthesis) I found is diluting the solution since the rate of 2nd order (intermolecular) reaction drops faster than 1st order (intramolecular) reaction. However, I wonder is it practical to dilute the solution to a large extent for purity, compromising the increased reaction duration and is there any faster and simpler reactions?

**question 2:**
This synthesis involves SN2, so I am thinking if there is a tertiary carbon bonded to the leaving group, it is impossible to form a cyclic ether. Therefore, are there any other ways I can synthesis cyclic ethers with the starting material as monohaloalcohol?

Comment: This is not an epoxide that you are making

Comment: High dilution is a well-recognised technique for favouring intramolecular cyclisations over inter, particularly in the cases of forming large rings

Comment: @Waylander Thanks for reminding. But may I ask under high dilution, what is the typical duration for the reaction?

Comment: Suspended NaH in refluxing diethyl ether. Add bromoalcohol in ether dropwise to the base. You will have to separate ether from the cyclic ether (THF). Notice I didn't use THF as a solvent.;)

Comment: High dilution reactions can be many hours with the reactant added by syringe pump.

Comment: Thank you all! I just found out I was drawing THF as the product...